# Why are components of vectors scalars?

Tags: vectors

Lets say we have a vector 1i+2j, I saw that the components of the vectors are said to be scalars, how can that be possible, doesnt 1i have a direction, also if they were a scalar why are the following vector laws of addition,

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Are-vector-components-scalar

Comment: "I saw that the components of the vectors are said to be scalars" Can you provide a reference for this b/c the context is important here. Some may say $1\boldsymbol{i}$ is the $\boldsymbol{i}$ component of your vector while others say that $1$ is the $\boldsymbol{i}$ component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably inviting down-votes to quote a Physics textbook on the Mathematics Stack Exchange, but at least this book, *Principles of Mechanics* by Synge and Griffiths, was well-respected in its time. The writers recognise that some people use "components of vector, **V**" to mean *vectors* in chosen directions that add (vectorially!) to make **V**. S and G call these, "vector components of **V**". These vector components can be thought of as products of unit vectors in the chosen directions, and scalar coefficients. Synge and Griffiths call the coefficients "the *scalar* components of **V**".

Distinguishing between "vector components" and "scalar components" removes ambiguity in how the term is being used. Although S and G were dealing exclusively with vectors in 3-dimensional space, the distinction could surely be carried over to more abstract vectors.

Comment: Upvote for referring to a physics textbook.

Answer (score 1):

The components in this context aren't $1\mathbf i$ and $2\mathbf j$, but $1$ and $2$.

And indeed, $\mathbf i$ and $\mathbf j$ are vectors, which can be (and are) scaled to make linear combinations.

Comment: $i,j$ are vectors, but the components are not vectors nor scalars. see comment below.

Answer (score 0):

1. The components of $1 \hat{i}+2\hat{j}$ are $1,2$ and not $1  \hat{i}, 2\hat{j}$
2. Components of vectors are not scalars, and not vectors- they are simply components of vectors.
   Scalars are objects who do not change under change of coordinates (e.g. if you rotate the axes by some angle). The components of a vector do change.
   **Example:**
   if we take some cartesian coordinates $x,y$, and the vector $\vec{V}= 2 \hat{x}+5\hat{y}$, if we take $x',y'$ to be coordinates which are rotated by $\pi/2$ we get $\vec{V}= 5 \hat{x'}-2\hat{y'}$. The components changed.  The vector length, hoever, *is* a scalar, as you can check.

Comment: "Scalars are objects who do not change under change of coordinates " So you would claim that *speed* is not a scalar?

Comment: @PhilipWood Speed is a 3-scalar, because a change of spatial coordinates does not change the speed. It is not a 4-scalar, because a change in spacetime coordinates (a moving train, for example) *does* change the speed.

Comment: "a change of spatial coordinates does not change the speed" I agree that if we rotate the spatial co-ordinates to a new fixed orientation, or translate them to a new fixed position, the speed won't change. Presumably changing to a co-ordinate system moving with constant velocity relative to the first system is not the sort of co-ordinate change you have in mind, as that would usually change the speed.